# The "most vexing parse", do we need to clear up confusion?

Tags: discussion, canonical

This [c++-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-faq) [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets) covers the [most-vexing-parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse). According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse), the term was coined by Scott Meyers in [Effective STL](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201749629). [Pedants](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197922/how-to-use-overloaded-operator-in-c#comment46608357_29197922) will say that the "most vexing parse" refers to a specific form of ambiguity resolution of the form:

```
std::ifstream ifs("file.txt"); 
std::vector<T> v(std::istream_iterator<T>(ifs), std::istream_iterator<T>());
```

And not:

```
MyObject  object();  // error
```

It's defined formally in §6.8 Ambiguity Resolution of the C++ standard(s). There is no mention of the "most vexing parse"<sup>1</sup>. But it's popularly used to refer to any form of syntactic ambiguity where an *expression-statement* is interpreted as a *declaration*.

I don't know the history of [Default constructor with empty brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/default-constructor-with-empty-brackets),  but judging from the revision history I suspect this happened:

- The [most-vexing-parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/most-vexing-parse) tag was created somewhere around 2009. The tag wiki uses a correct example of the "most vexing parse".
- The answerer calls it the "most vexing parse" and the question is retroactively tagged.
- Because the question is useful/popular, it was tagged as an FAQ 3 years later.

The title could use some reworking as well as it's hopelessly vague.

I can currently think of 3 approaches:

- Don't do anything, pedants will be pedants and the nomenclature reflects the usage.
- Clean up the FAQ question.
- Create a new FAQ question that specifically addresses §6.8, so that we have a canonical question and not confusing scattered bits and pieces.

Then perhaps a new tag could be created, something like [ambiguity-resolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ambiguity-resolution) and questions that don't specifically address the "most vexing parse" could be retagged.

---

<sup>1</sup> It should probably be called the "arbitrarily vexing parse" or "ambiguously vexing parse" instead.

Comment: Why would anyone who knows enough to use the tag need to ask a question about it?

Comment: @bmargulies Seems like many of the questions were tagged retroactively. However, if someone is using the tag deliberately they're probably asking a language lawyer esque question.

Comment: How about `object-construction` or something if you _really_ need a tag (and I honestly don't know why you do). There's nothing particularly vexing about it besides people failing to learn the language's basic syntax.

Comment: The canonical MVP example is governed by §8.2 [dcl.ambig.res], not §6.8 [stmt.ambig]. For `MyObject  object();` there is no ambiguity in the grammar at all, which doesn't permit using `()` as an initializer in this context.

Comment: @T.C. The problem is people calling "MyObject object();" the most vexing parse. I'm proposing a separate FAQ question for §6.8.

Comment: I am confused, are we discussing about the canonical question, the tag, yet-another-topic? The tags of this question says "canonical" yet the answer is about the tag?

Comment: @Braiam The answerer has made it clear that they don't think a canonical question would be necessary, and burninating the tag would be a better option.

Comment: The problem is the question. What exactly is the topic of this [meta-tag:discussion], the [tag] or the [canonical] question?

Comment: @Braiam I'm personally more in favor of just an FAQ question but it wouldn't make sense by itself unless you retagged some questions as well. It looks like another user has retagged some of the top questions.

Answer (score 43):

This tag is useless regardless.

We might as well start tagging questions [missing-constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/missing-constructor), [used-the-wrong-pointer-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/used-the-wrong-pointer-type), [invoked-undefined-behaviour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/invoked-undefined-behaviour)…

If somebody wants to know what the most vexing parse is, their question is a duplicate of the canonical question.

If somebody has an error and its due to the most vexing parse (or its non-vexing cousin, `A x()`) then their question is due to a "typo" of sorts and can no longer be reproduced. Thus, it should be closed as such. The OP simply and trivially used the wrong syntax by not reading their book properly.

I just can't see any use for tagging such questions, and the fact that people keep misusing it also makes me want to see it go.

Nuke it.

Comment: Agreed, tags should be used to allow people to follow a dedicated stream of questions; who would be interested in following `most vexing parse` questions oO ?

Comment: I am a most vexing expert! Err... um... wait a moment.  Let me reconsider that statement.

Comment: -1... I don't think a question should be closed just because the OP used the most vexing parse.

Comment: @Mehrdad: Why not? You want a million useless duplicates of silly syntax errors? What's the point in that?